# Stuck at how to proceed unit testing this business logic using tdd

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, logic

I have a method that I give a list of car movements (Operation class) in a parking lot (Entries,Exits) each movement has a related cars list (OperationVehicle class). This method should result what I called cars log. It lists all cars, at what time entered what time exited and the duration for each one.
I am a bit lost on what things to test first. An answer to this question would be like a tutorial for me.

How can I proceed on unit testing this particular logic using tdd ?

```
public class Operation
    {
        public Operation()
        {
            OperationVehicles = new List<OperationVehicle>();
        }
        public int OperationId { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public virtual OperationType OperationType { get; set; }
        public virtual List<OperationVehicle> OperationVehicles { get; set; }

    }

public class OperationVehicle
    {
        public int OperationVehicleId { get; set; }
        public OperationType OperationType { get; set; }
        public virtual Operation Operation { get; set; }
        public virtual Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
    }

public class CarLog
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
        public int StayLength { get; set; }
    }

   public IEnumerable<CarLog> GenerateCarsLog(List<Operation> CarStayOperations)
        {
           // not implemented yet
            return new List<CarLog>();
        }
```

Comment: Same as for any other method. You call the method with arguments, and check that what it returns is correct. What's the specific problem? Where's the code of your best attempt? Where's the code of the method to test?

Comment: I'm not stuck on how to write unit tests but what cases to test on this particular logic. By the way I'm new in unit testing. I did a lot of reading . but I always get stuck in real world code.

Comment: Test the nominal case first. Then, if there are special cases (empty list, or invalid arguments, or whatever), these these as well. Use your preferred code coverage tool to detect if you missed some cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have done so far is that you have modelled your domain in code (the relationships). But you haven't written much logic, so there's not much to test.

I wouldn't let your tests interact with these classes, at least not to start with. Rather, I would probably start somewhere around the user interface. Simulate the action that the user performs (and with user I don't necessarily mean a human being, but it could be another system). Test the behaviour, and do it as close to the boundaries of your system as possible.

Exactly what tests to write are hard to answer without more knowledge about the context. But I'll give it a try.

So what should the user be able to do with your system? For instance, write a first test where a car enters the parking lot and let the test assert in some way that the car is now in the parking lot.

But how would the user (or another user) know that the car successfully entered the parking lot? Is there, for example, some kind of user interface for the Car Log? Let your test's asserts look at that.

That would, however, be quite a large test to write, both including entering cars and checking the cars log. Perhaps better to start with the car log: just verifying that it is empty. Or perhaps there is an even smaller step you can start with?

My answer is a bit tentative, because that's what it is usually like: you learn and discover as you go.

*A design note: Please don't expose lists from your classes (`OperationVehicles`). It totally breaks encapsulation. Add a `Operation.AddOperationVehicle()` method instead and return an `IEnumerable<OperationVehicle>`.*

Comment: +1 for the advice that you should work from the outside in.  Part of the problem looks like you object model is more complex than need be, which is a result of you designing it out of the ether instead of driven by tests that specify what the utilizing system needs.

Comment: @Torbjörn Kalin thanks for your generous answer. I got some ideas from where to proceed. for a design note this model is actually a database model this is how most likely to be to generate my db using ORM like Entity framework.

Comment: @tallseth I think you're right my design is overloaded and really complex then it should be. I should simplify it. I think this is the main reason.